# Number and energy density integrals in cosmological thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology

I am working through Mukhanov's book "Physical Foundations of Cosmology" and something has me puzzled in the section on evaluating integrals for number density, energy density and pressure.

The number density and energy density are given by

$n=\frac{g}{2\pi^2}\int_m^\infty \frac{\sqrt{\epsilon^2-m^2}}{e^{(\epsilon-\mu)/T}\mp 1}\epsilon\;d\epsilon$

$E=\frac{g}{2\pi^2}\int_m^\infty \frac{\sqrt{\epsilon^2-m^2}}{e^{(\epsilon-\mu)/T}\mp 1}\epsilon^2\;d\epsilon$

He then makes a change of variables from $\epsilon$ to $x=\epsilon/T$ and introduces the new variables $\alpha=m/T$ and $\beta=\mu/T$, and then indicates that the following integrals are relevant in calculating $n$ and $E$ for particles and antiparticles:

$J_{\mp}^{(\nu)}(\alpha,\beta)=\int_\alpha^\infty \frac{(x^2-\alpha^2)^{\nu/2}}{e^{x-\beta}\mp 1}\;dx+\int_\alpha^\infty \frac{(x^2-\alpha^2)^{\nu/2}}{e^{x+\beta}\mp 1}\;dx$

However, in changing variables, the factors of $\epsilon(\rightarrow x)$ and $\epsilon^2(\rightarrow x^2)$ seem to have gone missing! Can anyone tell me if they have been absorbed somehow in the move to considering particles and antiparticles, or if there is some other explanation? It is tempting to think that this is just a typo, but the whole section that follows is related to evaluating these integrals and nowhere do the factors of $x$ and $x^2$ appear.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly, in the integrands you have something like

$$J^{(3)}+\alpha^2J^{(1)}\sim (x^2-\alpha^2)^{3/2}+\alpha^2(x^2-\alpha^2)^{1/2}=(x^2-\alpha^2)^{1/2}(x^2-\alpha^2+\alpha^2)=(x^2-\alpha^2)^{1/2}x^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Is it also possible to express the number density, n, as a linear combination of $J^{(1)}$ and $J^{(3)}$ or only in terms of the differential of $J$'s? The factor of $x$ seems more problematic than $x^2$.

Comment: Well, as stated in problem 3.8, the best one can do is calculate the difference between $n_p$ and $n_\bar{p}$. I think, if you calculate the left-hand side and the right-hand side of (3.37), you will see how to express this difference through $J^{(3)}$

Comment: Can you explain why it is not possible to calculate, say, just $n_p$, rather than the difference between the two n's? After all, there is a simple relation between n and p ($n=\frac{dp}{d\mu}$).

Comment: I did this calculation a few years ago, so of course I don't remember the details, but I guess that if you calculate $n=dp/d\mu$, you will get different signs depending on whether you are considering particles or antiparticles (since $\mu$ changes sign if you pass from particles to antiparticles). Therefore you get a minus sign in front of the antiparticle part and will end up with a difference rather than a sum as in the case of the energy density.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. I've been able to work through the whole section now, but there is one small thing that is troubling me, and that is: where does the extra condition $\alpha-\beta\gg 1$ come from in the nonrelativistic limit?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to justify this condition in a rigorous way. However, writing this as $m-\mu\gg T$ we see that this roughly amounts to the temperature being very small, much smaller than some, in some sense "reduced" mass $m-\mu$. And of course, in a non-relativistic limit we expect the temperature to be very small, so intuitively it makes sense. The only fishy thing is the scale $m-\mu$ we compare it to. I would just see this as a mathematical condition which simplifies calculations and roughly corresponds to a non-relativistic regime.

Comment: Having thought about it a bit more, I think it could be a condition for the particles to be non-degenerate (as well as non-relativistic), so that we can ignore the factor $\pm 1$ in the denominator of the integrals? However, this condition would usually be written $e^{(p^2/2m+mc^2-\mu)/kT}$ (in the non-relativistic case), so I am not sure where the exponential, and the $p^2/2m$ in the exponent, has diappeared to in Mukhanov's version of the condition...

Comment: I think, it is legitimate to assume $mc^2\gg p^2/2m$ in a non-relativistic limit, so the kinetic energy can be safely neglected. The exponential is monotonically increasing, so if $a\gg1$ then also $\exp(a)\gg 1$.